# I'm trying to figure out how to display different outputs based on what was selected in a list box. I'm doing something wrong I just don't know what

Tags: ruby, user-interface, shoes

It is suppose to put different outcomes based on what child is chosen from the list group, this is me just trying to figure out the basics. Eventually a similar structure will populate multiple flows with different data based on what child is selected from the list box
Here is my code:

```
       Shoes.app do
       para "Choose which child:"
       list_box :items => ["child 1", "child 2", "child 3"],
       :width => 120,
       :choose => "child 1" do |list|
       @child.text = list.text
       end

       @child = para "child 1"


 flow width:0.5, height: 0.5 do
  if @child.text = choose(item: "child 1") 
  para "you got this"
  elsif @child.text = "child 2"
  para "yes!!!"
  else
  para "think..think"
  end
end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

try this and let me know if it works like you expected. I hope I got your question right.

```
require 'green_shoes'

Shoes.app do
para "Choose which child:"
list_box items: ["child 1", "child 2", "child 3"],
:width => 120, choose: "child 1" do |list|
@child.text = list.text

if @child.text == "child 1"
  @test_stack.clear
  @test_stack.append {para "you got this"}
elsif @child.text == "child 2"
  @test_stack.clear
  @test_stack.append {para "yes"}
else
  @test_stack.clear
  @test_stack.append {para "think..think"}
end
end

@child = para "child 1"

@test_stack = stack width: 0.5, height: 0.5 do
  para "you got this"
end
end
```

Also, use double equals for condition checking. And you have to call the conditions inside the list box changes. As for the slot manipulation I usually clear it and then append to it, like above.

I'm using green shoes, but that shouldn't matter, just ignore the require.

regards,

seba